# Devices being unregistered after push is sent

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

This might sound weird, but I can't see any other explanation.

I've setup IBM Push Notifications on Bluemix, which I have done before. For some reason on this new app that i've built. Any time I send a push notification, it doesn't come through, I try to do so again and it tells me there are no devices.

This only happened to me today, maybe its an issue with the service?

Some things i've tried / noticed:

- My device is being registered and receiving successful messages from the service via the console.
- I only have 1 device, but monitoring is now telling me 7 devices have registered for notifications.
- When using the web console for sending push notifications, it says successful the first time (but nothing comes through), clicking again, says `Internal Server error: No devices found`.
- Using swagger docs, I input my appID and search for devices, none show up. I run the app, one shows up, I place the app in background, one still shows up. I send a notification through swagger, says successful, check for registered devices, returns empty array.
- Code in my iOS app is limited to the sample provided for the `IMFPush` / `IMFCore` cocoapods, for registering. I have no unsubscribe code of any kind.
- I have verified this without running any of my node.js code, or iOS code using only the swagger / web console tools.
- I'm using a sandbox provision profile I have used previously for a different app.
- I have deleted the IMF push service and recreated.

Any help / insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind providing your appID so we can look at our server-side logs and see if there is more debug information to be found there?

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM sure, its `2495eebe-8178-4bc0-882d-b42a86313b34` anything else give me a shout

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM tried to get it up and running. Deleted everything out of my bluemix including the other app that used the same sandbox cert. Only have this app running now and same thing has happened again. new appId is: `ea773cb6-f9d8-4249-b2a1-fc52eff496cf`

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM as I was attempting to swap to another cert / appId I noticed a typo in my app Id, this was causing the issue. However there appears to be a bug in IMFPush that its returning "Success" when there is in fact an error

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin can you please elaborate on what solved this issue. Where was the typo in your appID. I want to recreate the issue in my environment so I can open a proper defect

Comment: @Jaalger in my Xcode project i entered the wrong appId / bundle identifier for the app. E.g. the .p12 was created for `com.hello.world` I accidentally typed in `com.hllo.world` into my Xcode project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Simon please re-download the push sandbox certificate and export it from the keychain as .p12. This seems to have solve the problem. It seems strange though that a bad private key was giving you the "Invalid Token". so apple server is deleting the devices when you tried to send notification to invalid token devices. Please make sure you are following the right steps to generate the Sandbox or Production certificate https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_push_provider_ios.html

Comment: Hi Pradeep, This isn't the issue. As I mentioned above I'm reusing a .p12 i've previously used. My org has a large mobile team and creates reusable test credentials for various different things. I used this cert last week and it was fine. I took down that bluemix app and needed to build another and now i'm getting this weird behaviour. The IMFPush service is not returning any "invalid token" error to me. I'm getting "Success" followed by "No devices registered". Seems to be a bug in the service that its not returning the error, as well as whatever this issue is

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin is your issue resolved? Was the typo in your bundle ID the cause?

Comment: @DaveCariello yes its fixed. I must have been getting an "Invalid Token" from apple, but IMFPush was telling me success

Comment: @DaveCariello The certificate might have been revoked which was working before. Just check the certificate status is active in developers.apple.com, If  it is revoked the status should be invalid so please edit it and save. Configure push with edited  certificate and try sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

@SimonMcLoughlin found the root cause for this issue, it is because of bad private key. To resolve this issue just generate a .p12 certificate with .pem . For creating the p12 file with .pem file please follow the below method[image: Steps for creating p12 file]