# BlueMix push notification service loses device registrations?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have integrated BlueMix push notifications into my iOS app, and I have verified that the app can receive notifications. However, after some period of time, the app stops receiving them.

When I query the registered device list via REST API at `https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/devices` the device IDs I expect to be there are now gone from the list. What happened to the devices? Do they become unregistered by some automated process? Is there something I can do from the app side to make sure these devices do not become unregistered?

Comment: I had the same situation and this help me to solve my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840014/getting-stuck-with-creating-p12-push-certificate-file-for-bluemix-push

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some temporary issues with the Cloudant cluster that are manifesting themselves throughout the Bluemix Mobile Services. We're currently working with that team to get a resolution as fast as possible and will update when we know more.

To confirm that this is what is affecting your app: if you retry the request multiple times do you sometimes see some or all of the devices or are you getting an empty list each time?

Also to be clear; there is no intentional mechanic in the IBM Push Notifications service to prune or automatically delete device registrations.

Comment: It's not an empty list, but some devices that previously were on the list are gone. If I re-launch the iOS app on one of the missing devices, it reappears on the list for a while before disappearing again. "A while" can be anywhere from 15 minutes to several hours.

Comment: The Cloudant issues have been resolved, if you're still running into this issue please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898187/devices-being-unregistered-after-push-is-sent