# Getting stuck with Creating .p12 push certificate file for Bluemix push

Tags: ios, ssl, encryption, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

With reference to this post: [Devices being unregistered after push is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898187/devices-being-unregistered-after-push-is-sent), I have the same issue - my iPhone device is unregistered after sent a push notification.  I tried the suggestion from that post, and I did this with my certificates:

```
-ios_development.cer - Development profile downloaded from Apple 
-Certificates.p12 - APNS .p12 exported from the keychain 

-openssl x509 -in ios_development.cer -inform DER -out apns.pem -outform PEM
-openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem  
-openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey Certificates.pem -in apns.pem -out bluemixPush_dev.p12
```

and I got this error:

```
unable to load private key
97354:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:330:
97354:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:428:
```

Is anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

@Jan As your private key is wrong, you are getting that error. Please follow the steps mentioned in the below link to create a .p12 certificate.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_push_provider_ios.html#create-push-credentials-apns-ssl

[image: Create the .p12 push certificate file for Bluemix push]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried that many times and It did not work, I had different errors like No Certificate Match primary key and it could not load the key, so I was using a old backed application and push notification service, and I created theses in early this year, so I end up creating a new backend application and push service then I did not have to create a push certificate file for bluemix and it works using  the apns.p12 production environment